# Java looping issue

Tags: java, eclipse, while-loop

What this program does is takes words entered by the user and returns them in pig-latin form. The translation loop continues until the user enters "quit". My problem is that while the program executes and translates the words, after the word quit is entered the it translates "quit" which I don't want it to do. I know that the reason that it translates "quit" before finishing is that it's a do while loop but I'm stuck on how create a while loop that functions. How would I alter the program so that "quit" is what terminates the loop and isn't translated?
Example:
Word: quit
uit-qay

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.print("Word: ");
        word = input.next();

        System.out.println(pigLatinWord(word));
        System.out.println();
    } while (!word.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"));
    System.out.println("Translation complete");
}

// --------------------------------------------------------
// Convert one word to pig Latin.
public static String pigLatinWord(String s) {
    String pigWord;
    if (isVowel(s.charAt(0))) {
        pigWord = s + "-way";
    } else if (s.startsWith("th") || s.startsWith("Th")) { // or
                                                            // (s.toUpperCase().startsWith("TH"))
        pigWord = s.substring(2) + "-" + s.substring(0, 2) + "ay";
    } else {
        pigWord = s.substring(1) + "-" + s.charAt(0) + "ay";
    }
    return pigWord;
}

// ---------------------------------------------
// Determines whether c is a vowel character

public static boolean isVowel(char c) {
    String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    return (vowels.indexOf(c) >= 0); // when index of c in vowels is not -1,
                            // c is a vowel
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're executing `pigLatinWord(word)` before you get a chance to check if the word equals "quit". You can change the loop as such:

```
do {
    System.out.print("Word: ");
    word = input.next();
    if( "quit".equalsIgnoreCase(word) )
        break;
    System.out.println(pigLatinWord(word));
    System.out.println();
} while (true);
```

Comment: Isn't that the opposite?

Comment: You should not be negating `word.equalsIgnoreCase("quit");`

Comment: Thanks @dcharms and @BheshGurung, too much copy-pasting today. Also the new version helps avoid word being set to `null`.

Answer (score 1):

do {} while (); is generally bad to use, try to use while () {} instead. Like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean shouldQuit = false;
while (!shouldQuit) {
    System.out.print("Word: ");
    word = input.next();

    if (word.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
        shouldQuit = true;
    } else {
        System.out.println(pigLatinWord(word));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
System.out.println("Translation complete");
```

Or if you want to stick with do {} while, see the other answer.

Comment: You should use a `break` rather than instantiating another variable to check whether to break the loop or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible way.  Though, it'll involve not using a do-while.

```
//This is an infinite loop, except that we have our exit condition inside the 
//body that'll forcibly break out of the loop.
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Word: ");
    word = input.next();
    if (word.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
        break; //Whelp!  The user wants to quit.  Break the loop NOW
    }

    System.out.println(pigLatinWord(word));
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println("Translation complete");
```

Answer (score 1):

This one works, i tried it :)

```
  String word;
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Word: ");
  while(!(word = input.next()).equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
     System.out.print("Word: ");
     System.out.println(pigLatinWord(word));
     System.out.println("fsfafa");
   } 
   System.out.println("Translation complete");
```